# How to browse files in tree order to pick up the audio files available on sdcard and mobile memory in Android?

Tags: android, media-player

I need to browse a file tree in order to pick up the audio files.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the FileManager code from Open Intents:

http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ffilemanager

That will do exactly what you want.